# Placing a background video on a section of the page

Tags: html, css

The problem I am having is that I can't place the background video on just a section of the page without taking the whole page and when I manage to do that it extends to the whole page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav id='nav-bar'>
            <a class='nav-link' href="#home">Home</a>
            <a class='nav-link' href="#skills">Skills</a>
            <a class='nav-link' href="#projects">Projects</a>
            <a class='nav-link' href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
   <main>
        <section id='home'>
        </section>

        <section id='background-video'>
            <video autoplay loop muted>
            <source src="Beach.mp4">
            </video>
        </section>
</main
</body>
</html>
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: hsl(125, 73%, 55%);
}

:root
{
    --orange: hsl(41, 88%, 54%);
    --violet: hsl(295, 71%, 52%);
}

header
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 2rem;
}

/* Navigation Tabs */
.nav-link
{
    color: var(--orange);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 1rem;
}

/* Background Video */
#background-video, .yep, video
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    /* opacity: 0.8; */
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Just trying to get the background video to be only on the section after my header not the whole page. (Updated the header code missing)

Comment: There is no header in your code. If you want the element to start below an element your would have to tell it to be positioned that far down...not 100% of the height and width of the page.

Comment: Updated the code, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place it inside that section and set the `position` of the page to `relative` so the background video will be positioned relative to that section not the body. and then use another positioned container (overlay) with higher `z-index` to place your content obove the video.

Updated based on your comment: Then you should do the same but this time place it inside header. I have set a `min-height` for header so you can see the effect. That can be the size of your content or you can keep it if you want to have a fullscreen background.

```css
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: hsl(125, 73%, 55%);
}

:root
{
    --orange: hsl(41, 88%, 54%);
    --violet: hsl(295, 71%, 52%);
}

header
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 2rem;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

#nav-bar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

/* Navigation Tabs */
.nav-link
{
    color: var(--orange);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 1rem;
}

#home {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: red;
}

/* Background Video */
#background-video, video
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    background: blue;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <nav id='nav-bar'>
            <a class='nav-link' href="#home">Home</a>
            <a class='nav-link' href="#skills">Skills</a>
            <a class='nav-link' href="#projects">Projects</a>
            <a class='nav-link' href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </nav>
        <section id='background-video'></section>
    </header>
   <main>
        <section id='home'></section>
</main>
```

Comment: Hey I tried that but the video disappears and isn't that making the #home the section itself ? Looking to make the id='background-video' his own section below the header so like an introduction video but in a way I can also write on it and the rest of the content go normally bellow it.

Comment: @Tiago Updated the post check it out. you can also run the code too see how it's done.

Comment: Thank you it's working now this is exactly what I wanted.