# How to position youtube embedded video under another section since it has covered the entire page banner after making it responsive?

Tags: html, css, iframe, position, embedded-video

After moving things around, I tried to change the `position: absolute` to `position: relative` of the actual iframe class, it made the video position under 'Featured' but the dimension of the video is messed up. If I change it back to `position: absolute`, the video covers the entire page banner, but the responsiveness is good, however the dimension is too big. How do I make it look like the video is under the Featured page, aligned in the center, and responsive as well?

This is my code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display&display=swap');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap');



/*setting font size as 62.5%=10px for easier REM fontsize calculations*/
html, body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  height: 100%;   
  margin: 0;
  font-family: font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

/*making the image parallax as a banner*/
.parallax1 {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/6wPsROo.png);
  min-height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  opacity: .95;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-declaration: none;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: white;
  
}

/*customizing banner text*/
#slogan {
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1.5px 1px #A26B40;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.heading2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3.2rem;
}

#slogan-subheading {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: .5px .5px 1px #A26B40;
  font-weight: lighter;
  
}

#shop-now {
  background-color: #bd8d58;
  width: 10%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

#shop-now:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*make container for each row comprising an image with caption side by side*/
.prod-container {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/*customize each cell*/
.image-and-capt {
  padding: 10px 40px;
}


/*customize productimg*/
#product-img {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 15px rgba(182,124,72,0.3);
}

/*customize product name & description*/
#product-name, #product-descrp {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgba(54, 46, 39, 0.8);
}

#product-name {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#product-descrp {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-top: 4px;
 
}

.featured-container {
  background: rgba(255, 214, 170, 0.6);
  padding: 50px 100px;
}

.vid-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 0;
  
}

.vid-container-iframe {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
 
}

/*centering the logo and customizing size*/
#header-img {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: auto;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}

/*customizing the navigation links*/
.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #54473C;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  display: column;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  
  
  
}

/*customizing the actual navigation bar*/
#nav-bar {
  background-color: rgb(248, 234, 203);
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 50px;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  transition: 0.6s;
}

/*aligning the nav links on the right of the header image*/
nav ul {
  float: right;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

/*aligning the links to become horizontally aligned next to each other*/
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px 10px 5px 50px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

/* customizing appearance of nav-links when hovered*/
.nav-link:hover, nav-link:focus {
  background-color: #dcbd85;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: .5s;
  color: white;
}

/* customizing nav-link when focused or clicked */
.nav-link:focus {
  background-color: #dcbd85;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
}

/* customizing the three bars, making it invisible if in default full page view */
.check-bar {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #BF8D7A;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 5px;
  line-height: 80px;
  display: none;
}

/*making the checkbox invisible, this checkbox is used as a condition later, that when checked itll make the navlinks appear in a a specific media query*/
#check {
  display: none;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.products-container {
  background: #f6f7e9;
  padding: 50px 80px;
}

#sections {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 45%;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 4rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: rgba(54, 46, 39, 0.5);
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(54, 46, 39, 0.1); 
  line-height: 0.1em;
  margin: 10px 0 20px; 
}
h2 span { 
    background: #f6f7e9;
    padding: 0 10px; 
}
@media (max-width: 792px){
  .nav-link{
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }
  #header-img{
  max-width: 175px;
  max-height: auto;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 712px){
  .nav-link{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
  #header-img{
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: auto;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 675px){
  .nav-link{
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }
  #header-img{
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: auto;
  }
  nav ul li {
  
  padding: 25px 10px 5px 50px;
  margin-left: -30px;
}
}

@media (max-width: 675px){
  .nav-link{
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }
  #header-img{
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: auto;
  }
  nav ul li {
  
  padding: 25px 10px 5px 50px;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
}
/*configure what happens when you click three bars*/
@media (max-width: 500px){
  .check-bar{
    display: block;
  }
  /*center the logo , not yet done */
  #header-img {
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
  }
  ul{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%
    height: 100vh;
    top: 80px;
    /*when three bars are clicked the left bottom right values makes the whole ul disappear*/
    left: -100%;
    bottom: -100%;
    right: 100%;
    text-align: center; 
    background: rgba(255, 214, 170, 0.9);
    transition: all .5s;
    /* for stack, this makes the ul box in front of the parallax image since its z index is greater than the parallax*/
    z-index: 2;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .nav-link {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 60px
  }
  #check:checked ~ul {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  .nav-link:hover {
    background: none;
    color: #BF8D7A;
  }
  
  .parallax1 {
    z-index: 1;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 467px){
  #header-img{
    max-width: 190px;    
  }
   .nav-link {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }  
  
}

@media (max-width: 314px){
  #header-img{
    max-width: 200px;    
    margin: auto auto 0px auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  .nav-link {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }  
  .check-bar {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
  }
  #nav-bar {
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 271px){
  #header-img{
    max-width: 200px;    
    margin: auto auto 0px 0px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    
  }
  .nav-link {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }  
  .check-bar{
    font-size: 1.8rem;
  }
  #nav-bar {
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 251px){
  #header-img{
    max-width: 180px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    
    
  }
  .nav-link {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }  
  #nav-bar {
    padding-left: 8px;
  }
  .check-bar {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
    <header id="header">
      <nav id="nav-bar">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check">
        <label for="check" class="check-bar">
          <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </label>  
        <img id="header-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/zxchwt8.gif">
        <ul>
          <li id="nav-links-list"><a class="nav-link" href="#the-products">products</a></li>
          <li id="nav-links-list"><a class="nav-link" href="#featured" target=_blank>featured</a></li>
          <li id="nav-links-list"><a class="nav-link" href="#pricing" target=_blank>pricing</a></li>
          <li id="nav-links-list"><a class="nav-link" href="#contacts" target=_blank>contact</a></li>
        </ul></nav></header>
    <div class="parallax1">
      <div class="heading2">
        <span class="border">
          <h1 id="slogan">Pamper your skin.</h1>
          <h3 id="slogan-subheading">Cruelty-free, environmentally conscious, and organic.     </h3>.
          <span id="box"><h4 id="shop-now">SHOP NOW</h4></span
      </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="products-container">  
     <section id="the-products">
      <h2 id="sections"><span>products</span></h2>
      <div class="image-and-capt">        
      <div class="prod-container">
        <div class="image-and-capt">
        <img id="product-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/iSuRo4f.png" alt ="mock-up foundation">
        <h3 id="product-name"> Foundation with SPF 50 </h3> 
        <p id="product-descrp"> Medium-coverage, long-lasting, and available in 50 shades.
        </div> 
        <div class="image-and-capt">
        <img id="product-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/KSXpO9w.png" alt="moisturizer">
        <h3 id="product-name"> Moisturizer for All Skin Types</h3> 
        <p id="product-descrp"> Nourishing and brightening, reduces appearance of fine lines and wrinkles. 
         </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="prod-container">
         <div class="image-and-capt">
         <img id="product-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/cqzlfal.png" alt ="mock-up tinted moisturizer">
         <h3 id="product-name"> Tinted Moisturizer  </h3> 
         <p id="product-descrp"> Light-coverage with 50 shades, nourishing and brightening. 
        </div> 
        <div class="image-and-capt">
        <img id="product-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/UdInLk3.png" alt ="mock-up face wash">
        <h3 id="product-name"> Facewash  </h3> 
        <p id="product-descrp"> Gentle and hydrating facewash, thourougly cleanses dirt, make-up and sebum.</p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    </div>   
    <section id="featured">   
    <div class="featured-container">
      <h2 id="sections">featured</h2>
         <div class"vid-container">
           <iframe class="vid-container-iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MJMMZvBK6nU?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&color=white" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0"></iframe>           
         </div>
    </section></div>
    <section id="pricing">
    <p>Nam fermentum risus libero, ac ultricies leo faucibus nec. Nulla rhoncus nulla massa, dignissim finibus magna bibendum a. Morbi et aliquet justo, eu sagittis lectus. Quisque orci ipsum, aliquet ornare porttitor eget, fringilla quis purus. Integer eu semper eros. Donec quis libero at diam eleifend porttitor rutrum eu ipsum. Mauris sapien ipsum, gravida non ipsum sit amet, viverra facilisis mauris. Proin lacinia lectus vitae interdum condimentum. Quisque viverra sit amet diam ut finibus. Etiam nec ullamcorper magna.</p>
    </section>  
    <section id="contact">
    <p>Nam fermentum risus libero, ac ultricies leo faucibus nec. Nulla rhoncus nulla massa, dignissim finibus magna bibendum a. Morbi et aliquet justo, eu sagittis lectus. Quisque orci ipsum, aliquet ornare porttitor eget, fringilla quis purus. Integer eu semper eros. Donec quis libero at diam eleifend porttitor rutrum eu ipsum. Mauris sapien ipsum, gravida non ipsum sit amet, viverra facilisis mauris. Proin lacinia lectus vitae interdum condimentum. Quisque viverra sit amet diam ut finibus. Etiam nec ullamcorper magna.</p>
    </section>  
    </div>
    
      
          
</header>
</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Placing a background video on a section of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68730874/placing-a-background-video-on-a-section-of-the-page)

Comment: No, I don't actually want it to be the background video, just a content under a section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a mess to be honest. You have multiple `div` without closing tag,`p` without closing tags,
also some = are missing while declaring classes in your html code.

First go through your code, make sure that every single tag has a closing tag, after that continue with your video because if you dont fix these things, then your responsivity will be broken because of those unclosed tags.

Have a look into that, i have fixed the video so now it is under your featured section, you just have to play around with it to make it responsive after you closed every unclosed tag.

```
<section id="featured">
    <div class="featured-container">
        <h2 id="sections">featured</h2>
        <div class="vid-container">
            <iframe class="vid-container-iframe"
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MJMMZvBK6nU?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&color=white" width="560"
                height="315" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You're right my code is really messy, hahahahha. I'm new to coding and I guess I should practice more clean code. By the way when I decided to tidy up my code, I noticed what you noticed and guess what? That one missing equal sign on the video container made all the difference lmao, the video became responsive now and is under the featured section, It was not working before because the container was not properly declared. However, it's not in the center though, do you have any suggestions how can I make it in the center? I tried doing the display: block, margin: 0 auto already.